Stablizer expression(parity check matrix) to system Hamitonian for a quantum error correction code
Given a stablizer expression (parity check matrix) of a quantum error correction code, how to obtain its system Hamitonian? I am not sure whether this is correct: for toric code, its Hamitonian is just to substract all the stabilizer. Assume the stabilizer for toric code is $A_s=\otimes_j \sigma^Z_j$ and $B_p=\otimes_j \sigma^X_j$ on the loop of lattice and dual lattice, the system Hamitonian is $H = -\sum_sA_s -\sum_p B_p$. Refer to 1
If my understanding for toric code is correct, is the approach correct for all quantum error correction codes?

Yes, this approach is correct for all quantum error correcting codes. Note that only the stabilizer generators enter the hamiltonian, not all stabilizers.

if only the generators are considered, wouldn't that make the hamiltonian dependant on the choice of generators?...so the toric code for example could possibly have many hamiltonians; possibly with different properties

That indeed does make the hamiltonian dependent on the choice of generators. The different hamiltonians can also have different properties. For example for the toric code one could choose a set of stabilizer generators such that some errors anticommute with only one stabilizer generator (instead of the usual choice of stabilizers generators in which each error anticommutes with two or four).

that's why it's nicer to base definitions on all stabilizers...this way the "ground state of the toric code" becomes well defined...
